# DNS Hijack: Only spoofing sites listed in etter.dns

Tags: dns, dns-spoofing, ettercap

I'm trying to create a more practical DNS Hijack MITM attack. I do the traditional ARP poison with dns_spoof method. I don't have any issues getting it to work. The intended domain redirects exactly as expected. The only issue is that the current method isn't realistic. It would make a victim extremely suspicious because every other website would break. An attacker would need to count on the victim going to your domain immediately after you initiate the attack.

**ALL** websites not listed in the `etter.dns` host file gets redirected as well. How can we get ettercap to spoof ONLY the websites listed in `etter.dns` while forwarding everything else to their intended locations?

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following lines in /etc/ettercap/etter.conf

```
redir_command_on = "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i %iface -p tcp --dport %port -j REDIRECT --to-port %rport" 

redir_command_off = "iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i %iface -p tcp --dport %port -j REDIRECT --to-port %rport"
```

Note: You will need these lines uncommented if you plan on running SSLStrip.

Comment: what is the technical effect of uncommenting these lines?